# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.04: both don't boot

Tags: multi-boot

My computer loads up then gets to black screen and reads....

> Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 082)
> Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
>
> For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.0.0.4(03/03/09)
>
> CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 13 74 0 00 00 GUID: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
> PXE-E51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were recieved.
>
> PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM
>
> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
> or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Your computer is trying to boot via [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) (and fails doing so, since there is no PXE server of course), probably because it could not boot from hard disk. Check that the boot order in your BIOS setup is correct (booting from hard disk not disabled) and that the hard disk is detected in the POST messages. If it is not, check cabling between hard disk and mainboard. Also listen, if the drive spins up.

Did you change anything on your hardware, before the problem occured?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. It means that there is something wrong with your hard disk. Your PC cannot boot from it and it so is trying to boot from LAN and it fails.

How to fix it:

- is your disk detected in BIOS (if not, check physical connection of your HDD)
- check boot order in BIOS (my HDD was missing in Boot submenu of PhoenixBIOS (Toshiba) - i had to hit number 1 key and it appeared again)
- boot with install/recovery CD, go to the recovery mode with command line and try to fix your disk with chkdsk, fixboot (bootrec /fixboot) and fixmbr (bootrec /fixmbr) utilities